# MariaDB volume lose records when re-starting Docker containers

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-volume

I'm having a Laravel app running on Docker and I have Breeze installed. This is my setup

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    web:
        container_name: apache
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/apache/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./public:/var/www/html/public
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysql
        networks:
            - localnet
        env_file:
            - ./.env
            - ./docker/docker.env
    php:
        container_name: php
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        networks:
            - localnet
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        env_file:
            - ./.env
            - ./docker/docker.env
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mariadb:10.6
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./docker/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        ports:
            - "4306:3306"
        networks:
            - localnet
        env_file:
            - ./.env
            - ./docker/docker.env
networks:
    localnet:
        driver: 'bridge'
volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: 'local'
```

The docker.env contains the MYSQL_* variables which are required, so

```
// .env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelapp
DB_USERNAME=ltdev
DB_PASSWORD=secret

// docker.env
MYSQL_DATABASE="${DB_DATABASE}"
MYSQL_USER="${DB_USERNAME}"
MYSQL_PASSWORD="${DB_PASSWORD}"
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

// also runnin printenv | grep MYSQL_ shows me that the variables are set correctly
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_USER=ltdev
MYSQL_PORT=4306
MYSQL_DATABASE=laravelapp
```

Running also `docker-compose ps` I can see that the containers are running as expected

```
NAME                COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
apache              "httpd -D FOREGROUND"    web                 running             0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   mysql               running             0.0.0.0:4306->3306/tcp        
php                 "docker-php-entrypoi…"   php                 running
```

When the containers are up and running I register from the browser a new user and I can see the record show in the database.
However if I run `docker-compose stop` and then `docker-compose up -d` again the record is deleted from the database (i.e. doesn't persist) and the tables are empty. The same happens even if I switch the db image I use from `mariadb` to `mysql`.
I've been checking how to mount volumes and if I am doing something wrong there, but haven't spotted me doing anything different than the examples I've found or the documentation. Not sure if is related to the order of the containers starting, I have tried to play a little bit with the `depends_on`, but no luck. Any ideas what I am doing wrong??

This is the database after registering a new user

```
select id, name, email from users;
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| id | name      | email                 |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| 12 | Test User | test@test.com         |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

And this is after I run `docker-compose stop` and then `docker-compose up -d`

```
select id, name, email from users;
Empty set (0.000 sec)
```

Also the mysql logs

```
mariadbd, Version: 10.8.3-MariaDB-1:10.8.3+maria~jammy-log (mariadb.org binary distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                Id Command  Argument
220528  9:47:01      3 Connect  ltdev@172.24.0.5 on laravelapp using TCP/IP
                     3 Query    use `laravelapp`
                     3 Prepare  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Execute  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                     3 Execute  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Execute  SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
                     3 Execute  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  drop table `failed_jobs`,`migrations`,`password_resets`,`personal_access_tokens`,`users`
                     3 Execute  drop table `failed_jobs`,`migrations`,`password_resets`,`personal_access_tokens`,`users`
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
                     3 Execute  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Execute  select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'laravelapp' and table_name = 'migrations' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Execute  create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Execute  select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'laravelapp' and table_name = 'migrations' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
                     3 Execute  select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
                     3 Execute  select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select max(`batch`) as aggregate from `migrations`
                     3 Execute  select max(`batch`) as aggregate from `migrations`
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  create table `users` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Execute  create table `users` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`)
                     3 Execute  alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (?, ?)
                     3 Execute  insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values ('2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table', 1)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  create table `password_resets` (`email` varchar(255) not null, `token` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Execute  create table `password_resets` (`email` varchar(255) not null, `token` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  alter table `password_resets` add index `password_resets_email_index`(`email`)
                     3 Execute  alter table `password_resets` add index `password_resets_email_index`(`email`)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (?, ?)
                     3 Execute  insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values ('2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table', 1)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  create table `failed_jobs` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `uuid` varchar(255) not null, `connection` text not null, `queue` text not null, `payload` longtext not null, `exception` longtext not null, `failed_at` timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Execute  create table `failed_jobs` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `uuid` varchar(255) not null, `connection` text not null, `queue` text not null, `payload` longtext not null, `exception` longtext not null, `failed_at` timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  alter table `failed_jobs` add unique `failed_jobs_uuid_unique`(`uuid`)
                     3 Execute  alter table `failed_jobs` add unique `failed_jobs_uuid_unique`(`uuid`)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (?, ?)
                     3 Execute  insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values ('2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table', 1)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  create table `personal_access_tokens` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `tokenable_type` varchar(255) not null, `tokenable_id` bigint unsigned not null, `name` varchar(255) not null, `token` varchar(64) not null, `abilities` text null, `last_used_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Execute  create table `personal_access_tokens` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `tokenable_type` varchar(255) not null, `tokenable_id` bigint unsigned not null, `name` varchar(255) not null, `token` varchar(64) not null, `abilities` text null, `last_used_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  alter table `personal_access_tokens` add index `personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index`(`tokenable_type`, `tokenable_id`)
                     3 Execute  alter table `personal_access_tokens` add index `personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index`(`tokenable_type`, `tokenable_id`)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  alter table `personal_access_tokens` add unique `personal_access_tokens_token_unique`(`token`)
                     3 Execute  alter table `personal_access_tokens` add unique `personal_access_tokens_token_unique`(`token`)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (?, ?)
                     3 Execute  insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values ('2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table', 1)
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Query    START TRANSACTION
220528  9:47:02      3 Query    ROLLBACK
                     3 Quit
                     4 Connect  laravel@172.24.0.5 on laravelapp using TCP/IP
                     4 Query    use `laravelapp`
                     4 Prepare  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     4 Execute  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     4 Close stmt
                     4 Prepare  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                     4 Execute  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                     4 Close stmt
                     5 Query    START TRANSACTION
                     5 Prepare  insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                     5 Execute  insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('Arely Hoppe', 'langworth.adele@example.net', '2022-05-28 09:47:03', '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', 'QYnNmxKzse', '2022-05-28 09:47:03', '2022-05-28 09:47:03')
                     5 Close stmt
                     5 Query    ROLLBACK
                     5 Quit
                     6 Connect  laravel@172.24.0.5 on laravelapp using TCP/IP
                     6 Query    use `laravelapp`
                     6 Prepare  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     6 Execute  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     6 Close stmt
                     6 Prepare  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                     6 Execute  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                     6 Close stmt
                     6 Query    START TRANSACTION
                     6 Prepare  insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                     6 Execute  insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('Jayson Lind', 'jonathon.ritchie@example.com', NULL, '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', 'soG9Ck1eIN', '2022-05-28 09:47:03', '2022-05-28 09:47:03')
                     6 Close stmt
                     6 Query    ROLLBACK
                     6 Quit
    ...
    ...

// This is where the user gets added


220528  9:47:46     18 Connect  ltdev@172.24.0.8 on laravelapp using TCP/IP
                    18 Query    use `laravelapp`
                    18 Prepare  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                    18 Execute  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                    18 Close stmt
                    18 Prepare  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                    18 Execute  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                    18 Close stmt
                    18 Prepare  select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ?
                    18 Execute  select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = 'ltdev@laravelapp.com'
                    18 Close stmt
                    18 Prepare  insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                    18 Execute  insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('LT Dev', 'ltdev@laravelapp.com', '$2y$10$OY8YIf.x8s1IOW9zO8Zi8e1veMsv7ISKAWcMIZkE2o1Swy7cDYhpO', '2022-05-28 09:47:46', '2022-05-28 09:47:46')
                    18 Close stmt
                    18 Quit
                    19 Connect  laravel@172.24.0.8 on laravelapp using TCP/IP
                    19 Query    use `laravelapp`
                    19 Prepare  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                    19 Execute  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                    19 Close stmt
                    19 Prepare  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                    19 Execute  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                    19 Close stmt
                    19 Prepare  select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1
                    19 Execute  select * from `users` where `id` = 12 limit 1
                    19 Close stmt
                    19 Quit


// This is where the new session probably starts after compose up -d


mariadbd, Version: 10.8.3-MariaDB-1:10.8.3+maria~jammy-log (mariadb.org binary distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                Id Command  Argument
220528  9:48:01      3 Connect  laravel@172.24.0.3 on laravelapp using TCP/IP
                     3 Query    use `laravelapp`
                     3 Prepare  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Execute  set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                     3 Execute  set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Execute  SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
                     3 Execute  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  drop table `failed_jobs`,`migrations`,`password_resets`,`personal_access_tokens`,`users`
                     3 Execute  drop table `failed_jobs`,`migrations`,`password_resets`,`personal_access_tokens`,`users`
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
                     3 Execute  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Execute  select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'laravelapp' and table_name = 'migrations' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Execute  create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Execute  select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'laravelapp' and table_name = 'migrations' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
                     3 Execute  select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
                     3 Close stmt
                     3 Prepare  select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
                     3 Execute  select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
```

And this is what I get if I list the content of the file path inside the mysql/mariadb container where the data are stored

```
# ls -lah /var/lib/mysql/laravelapp
total 600K
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K May 29 20:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 mysql mysql 4.0K May 29 20:29 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql   67 May 29 20:29 db.opt
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2.6K May 29 20:29 failed_jobs.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 112K May 29 20:29 failed_jobs.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2.0K May 29 20:29 migrations.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  96K May 29 20:29 migrations.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 3.0K May 29 20:29 password_resets.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 112K May 29 20:29 password_resets.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 4.4K May 29 20:29 personal_access_tokens.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128K May 29 20:29 personal_access_tokens.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0K May 29 20:29 users.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 112K May 29 20:29 users.ibd
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, but perhaps you need to use [FLUSH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/flush/) before you stop the app?

Comment: You mean flush the privileges? I will give it a try although I don't think this is a mysql issue, rather more related to docker

Comment: I meant [flushing the tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/flush/#the-purpose-of-flush-tables). Again, I don't know if this will help. All I am thinking is that the rows you loose haven't been properly written to disk.

Comment: Yes, I gave it a try, but didn't improve anything. After restarting the containers there were no records again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know your environment well enough to help you.

Comment: Just noticed, there's some ROLLBACKs in your sql logs... where you try to insert a user for 'Arely Hoppe'. That probably doesn't tell why records are disappearing after container restart.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update - Debug

Try 1: Monitor with local folder mapping

Map to local directory (read-only binding) and observe the local file changes. You do read only binding so that you can observe the container folder/file updates are written to the local data folder but any local changes are not copied to the container. [Official Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume).

Try 2: External Volume

Docker can create volumes independent from containers. Try [create an independent volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes) and use [external](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose) flag for the volume in your compose yaml file.

#### Original Answer

This can be related to two issues, first of which is very less likely, being the location of data directory of your mysql container (MariaDB 10.6), which may vary depending on your container/hardware configuration.

Second is most likely that your docker version is not persisting the volumes, in which case you can map it to a local folder ... say like how you have mapped the `conf.d` (config file).

A possible third would be to remove the driver:local line from your volume.

Hope it helps!

Comment: For the 2nd you said, I have tried in mysql volumes this option `- docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql` but didn't work either (unless you are referring to something else). I have also tried to remove 3rd option you said and didn't work either. Can you explain more detailed the 1st?

Comment: You need to verify that /var/lib/mysql is really the path for the data directory in your mysql/mariadb container.

Comment: You can get into container shell with `docker exec -it -u 0 containerName bash`

Comment: I have updated the post adding the what I get if I ls the file path of the mysql/mariadb containers

Comment: This is btw after registering the user, but even if I restart my containers I see the same result, so the tables are there they are just empty of records